# Best way to create an array that goes 1-50 then 49-1 with only 1 loop

Tags: javascript

I know the best way to create an array that goes 1-50 then 49-1 would be 2 loops but this exercise requires us to use only 1 loop

```
    let myArr = [];
    let reachedFifty = false;
    let x = 1;

    for(i=0;i<100;i++){
        
        if(x == 50){
            reachedFifty = true;
        }

        myArr[i] = x;

        if(reachedFifty){
            x--;
        }
        else{
            x++;
        }
        
    }
```

This accomplished the task but the instructor said I'm using too much ifs and there are better solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the properties of the list to make this more efficient:

After filling the list with values it would look something like:

```
[1,2,3,4,.....,4,3,2,1]
```

We can see here that the list is symmetrical! By using this property, whenever we add a value on the "left" side, we can reflect it over to the right side:

```js
let myArr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  myArr[i] = i + 1;
  myArr[98 - i] = i + 1;
}

console.log(myArr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Notice how we are using the index at `98 - i` to reflect the changes across. This is because since there will be 99 total values, the value at index 0 should reflect to index 98, 1 to 97, etc.

I hope this helped answer your question! Please let me know if you need any further details or clarification :)

Comment: I was about to edit and then I realized you already did it T_T ty tho

Answer (score 2):

Why use any loops at all

```js
const max = 50
const t1 = performance.now()

const arr = Array.from({ length: max * 2 - 1 }, (_, i) =>
  max - Math.abs(i - (max - 1)))

console.log(`Took ${performance.now() - t1}ms`)
console.info(arr)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

This works by filling an array of length 99 with the evaluation of the expression

```math
50 - |index - 49|
```

For example

- `i = 0` -> `50 - |-49| = 50 - 49 = 1`
- `i = 1` -> `50 - |-48| = 50 - 48 = 2`
- ...
- `i = 49` -> `50 - |0| = 50 - 0 = 50`
- `i = 50` -> `50 - |1| = 50 - 1 = 49`
- ...
- `i = 98` -> `50 - |49| = 50 - 49 = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is that you could check for *i* instead of *x*, that way you'll only have an *if* and no need for a boolean variable.

```
let myArr = [];
let x = 1;

for(i=0;i<100;i++){
    
    myArr[i] = x;

    if(i >= 49){
        x--;
    }
    else{
        x++;
    }
    
}
```

But the symmetrical list approach is better, I think.